# Regex split but keep delimiter returning different than expected value

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a string that represents a simple mathematical equation over `+`, `-`, `<<` and `>>` while keeping the symbol. I can't find where the problem is.

```
>>> re.split(r'( \+ )|( \<\< )|( \- )|( \>\> )', 'x - x')
<<< ['x', None, None, ' - ', None, 'x']  # Expected ['x', '-', 'x']

>>> re.split(r'( \+ )| \<\< | \- | \>\> ', 'x - x')
<<< ['x', None, 'x']  # Expected ['x', '-', 'x']

>>> re.split(r'( \+ )| \<\< | \- | \>\> ', 'x + x')
<<< ['x', '+', 'x']  # The form I am looking for
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider the options as a single capturing group like this:

```
( \+ | \<\< | \- | \>\> )
```

Which can be used like

```
re.split(r'( \+ | \<\< | \- | \>\> )', 'x + x')
```